# Using wp-cli on remote with quoted commands

Tags: wp-cli, remote, ssh

I have my `wp-cli.yml` configured with a working ssh connection.

If I `wp db query "CHECK TABLE $(wp db tables | paste -s -d, -);"` and run locally it works just fine.

On the other hand, if I `wp @prod db query "CHECK TABLE $(wp db tables | paste -s -d, -);"`

I get "too many positional arguments"

if I `wp @prod option get home` - it works fine.

This leads me to conclude that the escaping of the remote command is causing the error - no amount of testing has revealed the "right" combination of single/double-quotes to get the command to the remote server.

Suggestions?

Comment: are you sure both your local and remote environments are using the same shell? How do you know which command has the issue when there are at least 3 commands nested on the same line? Have you tested the inner shell inside `$()` works as expected with the desired output? _What are you actually trying to do?_ This looks like a classic X Y problem where you asked how to fix your solution rather than how to solve your problem

Comment: Looks like a sub-shell problem. Maybe can be fixed by more escaping. What does `wp @prod db query "CHECK TABLE ${wp db tables | paste -s -d, -};"` or `wp @prod db query "CHECK TABLE {$(wp db tables | paste -s -d, -)};"` do?

Comment: Indeed @TomJNowell - I wrote this with an example that illustrated my issue. I am using different shells (zsh locally, bash on the remote). Ultimately - I am trying to use wp-cli to run a db query on the remote - unsuccessfully. This is an example I borrowed from the wp-cli examples - i.e unlikely that it was a user-induced error.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for the input - the first above returns "bad substitution" from zsh & the second runs on the remote and returns Error: Too many positional arguments: TABLE wp_blog_aliases wp_blog_aliasmeta wp_blogmeta wp_blogs wp_commentmeta wp_comments wp_links wp_options wp_postmeta wp_posts wp_registration_log wp_signups wp_site wp_sitemeta wp_term_relationships wp_term_taxonomy wp_termmeta wp_terms wp_usermeta wp_users

Comment: oooooh I see that your substitution is inside the string, so `wp db tables` is going to run locally, not remotely on `@prod`. If you're going to nest commands you need to be sure all of them work individually, testing them all at once together makes it difficult to track down problems

Comment: @TomJNowell - ah that was just the mental clue I needed to sort this out. I'll post a working example as soon as I get it working!